# C# - I want to display an error when I input String in a ConvertToDecimal function

Tags: c#, winforms

Hi I would like the program to display an error message when I input a String, I have tried to use some solution online but it doesn't work on mine, would be really appreciate if could solve it for me thanks very much.

```
 //Price must be numeric

        if(txtPrice.Text == String.txtPrice)//There is an error on this I can't figure it out
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Price must be numeric", "Error!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            txtPrice.Focus();
            return;
        }
 //price must be a positive number

        if( Convert.ToDecimal(txtPrice.Text) <= 0)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Price must be a positive number", "Error!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            txtPrice.Focus();
            return;
        }
```

Comment: use `Decimal.TryParse`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think in your case would be better to try to convert **txtPrice.Text** value to **Double** at first.

Here's a link to [decimal.tryparse](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.decimal.tryparse?view=netframework-4.8).

The code would look like:

```csharp
decimal price;
//Price must be numeric
if(!Decimal.TryParse(txtPrice.Text, out price))
{
  MessageBox.Show("Price must be numeric", "Error!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
  txtPrice.Focus();
  return;
}
//price must be a positive number
if(price <= 0)
{
  MessageBox.Show("Price must be a positive number", "Error!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
  txtPrice.Focus();
  return;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use this code

```
try{
  double x = Convert.ToDecimal(txtPrice.Text)
 }
 catch(Exeption e){
 MessageBox.Show("Price must be a positive number", "Error!", 
 MessageBoxButtons.OK,MessageBoxIcon.Error);
 }
```

Comment: When answering with code, it's always better to add an explanation as to why it answers the original question. Also, this code should be indented, and catch a less generic error than the base class `Exception`.